# NoSuchElementException after switching frames

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, junit

**UPDATE**:

I think I saw the error, I configure again my Selenium IDE and recreate the test, and when i open in Eclipse i see this comments in code:

```
public void testEcsf3() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/something.com");
    WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.name("body"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
    //...
    //code for navigate to the target page
    //...
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=body | ]]
    //Target page - another frame with name 'body'
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[28]/td[2]/a/font")).click();// <-- target element in target page
   //...
    //code for navigate to the target page
    //...
  }
```

The problem is that the flow between pages have more of one frame with name 'body'(i can't change that), how i can make this work?
Thanks.

--

I'm trying to use a Selenium testcase(Ok in browser) using JUnit in Eclipse.
When I try to run the testcase I receive this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"user"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

Note: the link mentioned in the error has no content!
This is the point of error:

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "/something.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("user")).sendKeys("aaa"); //<--
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxx");
driver.findElement(By.name("button0")).click();
```

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using? Sounds like an old one.

Comment: I'm using latest version, 2.35.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the following:
This line: `driver.get(baseUrl + "/something.com");` says him to go to this page, and the second line says him to search for the element immediately (so the browser dont have time at all to load the page)

So try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait; 
wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10);
try{
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("user")));
}catch(TimeoutException e){
verifyElementPresent(locator);
}
```

or:

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
    if (second >= 60)
        fail("timeout");
    try {
        if (isElementPresent(By.name("user"))) {
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Hi jollyjoyce1995, thanks for attention.
I try your sugestion, but not work.
This is the code:

  public void testEcsf3() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/something.com");
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    try{
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("user")));
    }catch (Exception e) {
     isElementPresent(By.name("user"));
 }
 ...
 }

Note: I'm using FirefoxDriver(generate by Selenium IDE code).

Answer (score 0):

Are you bound to the Driver? you could try this:

```
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver,"http://example.com");
selenium.open("http://something.com");
```

and optionally a

```
selenium.waitForPageToLoad();
```

The other things you tried to do are also simpler with the `WebDriverBackedSelenium` like

```
selenium.type(String field,String text);
```

you can look at [that](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html) for the javadoc and deeper explanation

Comment: I'm using the FireFox driver, generate in testcase in Selenium IDE
private WebDriver driver;
...
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
I think is interesting stay with this driver, only changing if it is the only onption(I'm wrong?).
Thanks.

Comment: ok, so you could construct the WebDriverBackedSelenium object with your driver as parameter

Answer (score 0):

I stop for some days this project, and today i resolve the trouble.
This is the code:

```
    for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
    WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.name("body"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(body);
```

I hope this help someone.
Thanks.